# tar Exiting with failure...?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, shell, tar

i'm untaring with this command `tar -pxvzf filename.tar.gz` an everything seems to be going fine but, it unexpectedly exits with the error below. Is there a reason why I'm receive this error and / or prevent it?

```
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Followed the suggestion from people who replied and removed the -v. this is the output errors (see below). This is a backup of a joomla cms site. Any idea what would cause these errors? The only thing I could thing of is the cache and tmp folders might be causing it with the weird characters that it may have

```
tar: Archive contains `nsion.pd' where numeric mode_t value expected
tar: Archive contains `Party.pd' where numeric mode_t value expected
tar: Archive contains `manent C' where numeric mode_t value expected
tar: Archive contains `ial Circ' where numeric mode_t value expected
tar: Archive contains `pdf0444' where numeric mode_t value expected
tar: Archive contains `pring 20' where numeric mode_t value expected
tar: Archive contains `.pdf444' where numeric mode_t value expected
tar: Archive contains `pdf0444' where numeric mode_t value expected
tar: Archive contains `up from ' where numeric mode_t value expected
tar: Archive contains `ting.pdf' where numeric mode_t value expected
tar: Archive contains `on.pdf4' where numeric mode_t value expected
tar: Archive contains `f100444' where numeric mode_t value expected
tar: Archive contains `ptions t' where numeric mode_t value expected
tar: Archive contains `f100444' where numeric mode_t value expected
tar: Archive contains `pdf0444' where numeric mode_t value expected
tar: Archive contains `f100444' where numeric mode_t value expected
tar: Archive contains `ter.pdf' where numeric mode_t value expected
tar: Archive contains `ted.pdf' where numeric mode_t value expected
tar: Archive contains `df00444' where numeric mode_t value expected
tar: Archive contains `Inc..pdf' where numeric mode_t value expected
tar: Archive contains `d.pdf44' where numeric mode_t value expected
tar: Archive contains `Network.' where numeric mode_t value expected
tar: Archive contains `df00444' where numeric mode_t value expected
tar: Archive contains `rship Aw' where numeric mode_t value expected
tar: Archive contains `.pdf444' where numeric mode_t value expected
tar: Archive contains `ition.pd' where numeric mode_t value expected
tar: Archive contains `df00444' where numeric mode_t value expected
tar: Archive contains `9.pdf44' where numeric mode_t value expected
tar: Archive contains `1.pdf4' where numeric mode_t value expected
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Comment: try removing the -v flag to see the real error why that is happening.

Answer (score 3):

Your command will invoke `tar` which will invoke `gunzip` to uncompress the file first. You can use two commands to check for possible errors like file corruption as follows:

```
$ gunzip filename.tar.gz
```

The above command will produce the file `filename.tar`. Then, you can use:

```
$ tar -pxvf filename.tar
```

This should help you in debugging the problem. You can also remove the `-v` from the command to disable files listing which may help you to focus on the error messages only.

Comment: Removing the 'v' from the tar command will reduce the output too and may aid in seeing other relevant messages